# Set Relations Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I understand these laws when applied to certain situations but can't seem to understand how to apply it to these problems. I know that if Jon is Mike's cousin, then Mike is Jon's cousin and that is a Symmetric relation. I also know that if Jon is taller than Mike and Mike is taller than Maddie, then Jon is taller than Maddie and that is a Transitive relation. How do I make the step to these type problems using the same thought system?

```
For each the following relations on the set of integers list all that apply
(Reflexive, Symmetric, Antisymmetric, or Transitive):

R1 = {(a, b) | a * b <1}
```

Comment: The underlying set over which $a$ and $b$ roam can make some difference in the answers. Is it the reals? The positive reals? The rationals? The integers? If you are looking at a homework or practice question, the question would say.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. It asks for integers.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hints: for $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z\;$ :

$$ab<1\iff ba<1\;,\;\;\\0^2<1\;,\;\;\text{but if}\;\; a\neq0\;\;\text{then}\;\;\;a^2\ge 1\\2\cdot(-1)<1\;\;\wedge\;\;(-1)\cdot 1<1\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;2\cdot 1>1$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the definition that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R_1$, or $a\mathbin{R_1}b$ for short, if and only if $ab<1$. To decide whether $R_1$ is symmetric, you should ask yourself:

> If $a\mathbin{R_1}b$, is it always the case that $b\mathbin{R_1}a$?

In the case of cousinship, you’re asking:

> If Jon is cousin to Mike, is it always the case that Mike is cousin to Jon?

For cousinship the answer is clearly *yes*. For $R_1$ you want to use the definition of $R_1$ to translate $a\mathbin{R_1}b$ into something more fundamental. By definition $a\mathbin{R_1}b$ means that $ab<1$, and $b\mathbin{R_1}a$ means that $ba<1$. Thus, the first question becomes:

> If $ab<1$, is it always the case that $ba<1$?

And in this form it’s clear that the answer is *yes*, since we know that $ab=ba$, so $R_1$ is symmetric.

To decide whether $R_1$ is transitive, you should ask yourself:

> If $a\mathbin{R_1}b$ and $b\mathbin{R_1}c$, is it always the case that $a\mathbin{R_1}c$?

In the case of the relation *taller than*, you’re asking:

> If Jon is taller than Mike, and Mike is taller than Maddie, is it always the case that Jon is taller than Maddie?

Of course the answer is *yes*, and we conclude that the relation is transitive. To answer the question for $R_1$, we should again use the definition to translate it into something more basic. The statements $a\mathbin{R_1}b$, $b\mathbin{R_1}c$, and $a\mathbin{R_1}c$ mean $ab<1$, $bc<1$, and $ac<1$, respectively, so the question can be rewritten as follows:

> If $ab<1$ and $bc<1$, is it always the case that $ac<1$?

When is a product of two integers less than $1$? This happens when at least one of integer is $0$, and when one is positive and the other negative, and that’s it. So if $a$ and $c$ are positive, and $b$ is negative, the products $ab$ and $bc$ will both be negative, but the product $ac$ will be positive. To make this concrete, let $a=c=1$ and $b=-1$: then $ab=-1<1$, and $bc=-1<1$, but $ac=1\not<1$. This counterexample shows that $R_1$ is **not** transitive.

The question for reflexivity:

> Is it always the case that $a\mathbin{R_1}a$?

It translates to:

> Is it always the case that $a^2<1$?

Of course the answer is *no*: it’s almost **never** the case that $a^2<1$ when $a$ is an integer — it’s the case only when $a=0$. $R_1$ is not reflexive.

For antisymmetry the question is:

> If $a\mathbin{R_1}b$ and $b\mathbin{R_1}a$, can I always conclude that $a=b$?

And the translation:

> If $ab<1$ and $ba<1$, can I always conclude that $a=b$?

Again it’s easy to find counterexamples showing that the answer is *no* and hence that $R_1$ is not antisymmetric: for example, take $a=1$ and $b=-1$.